# How to make a button default setting after pressing button in javaFM

Tags: java, javafx

I need to make a picture change based on the button pressed.

A face needs to have an arc for a smile when smile button is pressed, the face needs to have an opposite arc for a frown when i press frown button and the face needs to have a flat line when pressing think button.

I have managed to do this, but it seems one i press the think button it sets the radiusY permanently and does not allow it to revert back to the default.

eg - when i press 
smile - all fine
frown - all fine
think - all fine
after using the think button - frown - does not return to the original
after using the frown button - smile - does not return to the original

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.scene.Group; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.control.Button; 
import javafx.scene.layout.Background; 
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox; 
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox; 
import javafx.scene.paint.Color; 
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc; 
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType; 
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle; 
import javafx.scene.text.Font; 
import javafx.scene.text.Text; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class Changingsmile extends Application {

     @Override     
     public void start(Stage stage)     
     { 

         Circle face = new Circle(125, 125, 80);          
         face.setFill(Color.YELLOW);         
         face.setStroke(Color.RED);  

         Circle rightEye = new Circle(86, 100, 10);         
         rightEye.setFill(Color.YELLOW);         
         rightEye.setStroke(Color.BLUE); 

         Circle leftEye = new Circle(162, 100, 10);         
         leftEye.setFill(Color.YELLOW);         
         leftEye.setStroke(Color.BLUE);   


         Arc mouth = new Arc(125, 150, 45, 35, 0, -180);          
         mouth.setFill(Color.YELLOW);         
         mouth.setStroke(Color.BLUE);         
         mouth.setType(ArcType.OPEN); 

         Text caption = new Text(68, 240, "Changing smile");         
         caption.setFill(Color.BLUE);         
         caption.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", 15));


         Group group = new Group(face, rightEye, leftEye, mouth,  caption); 


         Button smileButton = new Button("Smile"); 


         Button frownButton = new Button("Frown"); 

         Button thinkButton = new Button("Think"); 

         HBox buttonBox = new HBox(10);         
         buttonBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 


         buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(smileButton, frownButton, 
         thinkButton);

         VBox root = new VBox(10); 
         root.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);         
         root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 

         //add the button box and the face group to the vertical container         
         root.getChildren().addAll(buttonBox, group);

         // create and configure a new scene         
         Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 275, Color.YELLOW);

         // supply the code that is executed when the smile button is pressed  
         smileButton.setOnAction(e -> mouth.setLength(-180));

         // supply the code that is executed when the frown button is pressed   
         frownButton.setOnAction(e -> mouth.setLength(180)); 

         thinkButton.setOnAction(e -> mouth.setRadiusY(0));



         stage.setScene(scene);         
         stage.setTitle("Changing Smile");  


         stage.show();             
    }         

     public static void main(String[] args)     
     {         
         launch(args);     
     }
}
```

Comment: If you want the radiusY to be something other than zero when other buttons are pressed, perhaps those buttons’ onAction code should actually set the radiusY to a value other than zero?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply include in the buttons onAction a `mouth.setRadiusY(35)`, which should fix the issue because it's then resetting that value on the press of another button.

To set the onAction for a JavaFX button, use something like this:

```java
Button smileButton = new Button("Smile"); 
smileButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        mouth.setRadiusY(35);
        mouth.setLength(-180)
    }
});
```

Or, as @fabian suggested:

> replace the single statement to the right of the -> in the lambda expression with multiple statements surrounded by {}, e.g. `smileButton.setOnAction(e -> { mouth.setRadiusY(35); mouth.setLength(-180); });`, if you want to keep using lambda expressions
>   -fabian

Comment: Thank you, how do you include multiple instructions on one onAction

Comment: @taz3345 I have updated my answer explaining how to create an EventHandler within setOnAction()

Comment: @taz3345 replace the single statement to the right of the `->` in the lambda expression with multiple statements surrounded by `{}`, e.g. `smileButton.setOnAction(e -> { mouth.setRadiusY(35); mouth.setLength(-180); });`, if you want to keep using lambda expressions.